# Form's input button smaller that div based button

Tags: css

Dont know why the form's input button of the right (Aceptar) is smaller than the div made button of the left when the CSS is the same (except for a general border: 0 on the input's).

[image]
Any clues? CSS below:

```
Div button:
.boton {
    width: 5em;
    background-color: #8d99ae;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2b2d42;
    padding: 0.1em;
    display: inline-block;
}

Input button:
input#boton {
    width: 5em;
    color: #edf2f4;
    background-color: #8d99ae;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2b2d42;
    padding: 0.1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Most likely your browser is applying some defaults to inputs. You need a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

Comment: This is very hard to tell just from the code you are posting. There might be more inherited values. Ca you make your page public so we can access it and check from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

As Andrei mentionned, you should include a CSS reset. But I'm pretty sure that in your case, setting a "line-height" value would solve the issue.

Comment: Im already using css resetters, tried two, no luck. Line-height did not do the trick.